# Accessing QTableWidget's data from another class

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I've got a child widget (it's a configuration dialog to my `MainWindow`) with a `QTableWidget` on it.

panelSettingsDialog.h:

```
 public:
    explicit PanelSettingsDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PanelSettingsDialog();

  public:
     QTableWidget *tableWidget;

  private:
     PanelSettingsDialog *panelSettingsDialog;
```

panelSettingsDialog.cpp:

```
 #include "panelsettingsdialog.h"
 #include "ui_panelsettingsdialog.h"

 #include <QCheckBox>


 PanelSettingsDialog::PanelSettingsDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PanelSettingsDialog)
  {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setWindowTitle("Channel Settings & Panel Configuration");

    tableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
```

`tableWidget` populates as expected (I added 5 dummy rows of data).

Now I intend to access this useful `QTableWidget` information from my `MainWindow` class by iterating through each of the rows, using the `panelSettings->tableWidget->rowCount()` statement, but get a read access error when trying to use the `rowCount()`:

mainwindow.cpp:

```
 void MainWindow::configure_panels()
 {
     const int totalRowCount = panelSettingsDialog->tableWidget->rowCount();
 }
```

breaks here, with the following error message:

*Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x64098ffa, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance).*

If I am unable to read from another child class's widget items, what would a good method be for passing `QTableWidget` data to `MainWindow` so that it can be iterated through?

@Chernobyl , perhaps you may have the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableWidget` should be private. When we write app with Qt Designer we always use our `ui` in private section, because  if we will use it as public, we can get problems. We should separate this things. tableWidget should be private, but we should provide some public methods which will do what we want. I think you can use getters and setters.

For example:

dialog.h

```
public:
    int getRowCountData();
```

dialog.cpp

```
    int Dialog::getRowCountData()
    {
        return ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    }

//... somewhere in constructor

    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
    for(int r=0;r<7;r++)
    {
     ui->tableWidget->insertRow(r);
     ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(r,0,new QCheckBox(QString("checkBox%1").arg(r)));
    }
```

Usage:

```
void MainWindow::on_newForm_clicked()
{
    Dialog *mDialog = new Dialog;
    mDialog->setModal(true);
    mDialog->show();
    qDebug() << mDialog->getRowCountData();
}
```

You'll see `7`. And so on with other things.

Edit (same structure):

```
QString getCellData(int row,int col);//in header
```

In .cpp

```
QString Dialog::getCellData(int row, int col)
{
     QCheckBox* curBox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(row,col));
     if(curBox)
     {
        return curBox->text();
     }
     return QString();
}
```

Usage:

```
Dialog *mDialog = new Dialog;
mDialog->show();
qDebug() << mDialog->getRowCountData();
for(int r=0;r<7;r++)
{
    QString txt = mDialog->getCellData(r,0);
    if(!txt.isNull())
        qDebug() << txt;
    else
        qDebug() << "fail";
}
```

Comment: thank you, yes that definitely sounds on point for RowCount, however I am interested in communicating every cell's data (via something like a QVector < QVector < QString > >) or something. Have you done something like this with all the table data? Thanks :)

Comment: @Rachael Are you want get data from dialog's cells in mainWindow or you want set date in this cells?

Comment: just get the data (I use properties from the grid to instantiate the correct number of widgets in mainWindow, which take on some of the values from their respective rows from tableWidget). the vector array will vary in size.

Comment: wonderful. Yes, that works. I should have thought about your answer to my other question yesterday more thoroughly. I was fixated on creating some kind of array to re-store all the data.

Comment: @Chernobyl--I'm getting a read access error when using any function returned by the ui (rowcount(), columnCount(), etc.)...any ideas? I made the functions public in my dialog header, of course.

Comment: @Rachael It is very hard to predict something without code which causes error.

Comment: @Chernobyl--sorry about that. I was thinking it was something simple with the access levels of the functions themselves. Disregard that comment I suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61449/discussion-between-rachael-and-chernobyl).